# Receiving error when generating dates (ERROR: "Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument"

Tags: r, data-generation

I am working on a project that requires us to generate an x number of dates. The code had been running well, however there is now an error that comes up roughly 40% of the time when I attempt to run the function, "Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument". If someone would be willing to look at my code relating to the dates to see if they can find the root cause of this problem it would be most appreciated, thanks!

`dates <- sample(seq(as.Date('2010/03/15'), as.Date('2015/11/24'), by = "day"), length(x))`

`dates <- as.Date(dates)`

edit: the error disappears when I sort the dates by inserting

`dates <- sort(dates)`

after the lines of code above. However, I do not want to sort these randomly generated dates, I need them to remain unsorted.

Comment: Do the dates `as.Date('2010/03/15')` and `as.Date('2015/11/24')` change in your code?

Comment: It does not give me any error. I think your x must be null and therefore length(x) = 0,  could you check?